# Why couldn't India grow its economy as fast as China did?

Tags: gdp, china

I was listening to [this debate on India vs China](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yC-2QVOQcg8). Professor [Dr. Kishore Mahbubani](https://mahbubani.net/) posed this question (watch from 17:21).

Let us see the [following graph](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.PP.CD?locations=IN-CN):

[image]

India has a population comparable to China. But, the size of its GDP is much lower. Also, India's [wealth gap is horrible](https://www.hindustantimes.com/india-news/in-india-inequality-bigger-challenge-than-poverty/story-i5bvo7P2vVOEHOngFX5n1K.html).

Why couldn't India grow its economy as fast as China did?

**Note:** I am interested in 1978 and onward as [Deng Xiao Ping's economic reform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_economic_reform) came around this time.

Comment: It is as you say, greater inequality and less state management has held India back.

Comment: Some references: *China's Lessons for India* (2017), *China and India: A Tale of Two Economies* (2006), *India's and China's Recent Experience with Reform and Growth* (2005).